# Template trick to optimize out allocations

Tags: c++

I have:

```
struct DoubleVec {
  std::vector<double> data;
};

DoubleVec operator+(const DoubleVec& lhs, const DoubleVec& rhs) {
  DoubleVec ans(lhs.size());
  for(int i = 0; i < lhs.size(); ++i) {
    ans[i] = lhs[i]] + rhs[i]; // Assume lhs.size() == rhs.size()
  }
  return ans;
}

DoubleVec someFunc(DoubleVec a, DoubleVec b, DoubleVec c, DoubleVec d) {
  DoubleVec ans = a + b + c + d;
}
```

Now, in the above, the "a + b + c + d" will cause the creation of three temporary DoubleVec's. Is there a way to optimize this away with some type of template magic? I.e., to optimize it down to something equivalent to:

```
DoubleVec ans(a.size());
for(int i = 0; i < ans.size(); i++) 
  ans[i] = a[i] + b[i] + c[i] + d[i];
```

You can assume all DoubleVec's have the same number of elements.

The high level idea is to have do some type of templated magic on "+", which "delays the computation" until the =, at which point it looks into itself, goes hmm ... I'm just adding these numbers, and synthesizes a[i] + b[i] + c[i] + d[i] ... instead of all the temporary variables.

Comment: Since the parameters to operator+ are const references, a smart compiler might do this automatically. Have you checked?

Comment: For this particular case, the easiest thing to do would be to overload `operator+=` and use that instead.

Comment: I think the [Eigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page) library does exactly what you want and achieves lazy evaluation with expression templates.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yep, that's exactly what *expression templates* (see http://www.drdobbs.com/184401627 or http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Expression-template for example) are for.

The idea is to make `operator+` return some kind of proxy object which represents the expression tree to be evaluated. Then `operator=` is written to take such an expression tree and evaluate it all at once, avoiding the creation of temporaries, and applying any other optimizations that may be applicable.

Comment: Exactly what I need. Would do business again. A++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

Comment: Qt's QString does this, but with a different operator, namely operator% and uses QStringBuilder for it. It's not well-documented, so they may choose to remove it in the future.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [Boost.Proto](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/doc/html/proto.html), which is a library for writing [EDSL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-specific_language#External_and_Embedded_Domain_Specific_Languages) (embedded domain specific languages) directly in C++. There is even [an example](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/doc/html/proto/users_guide.html#boost_proto.users_guide.examples.tarray) showing exactly what you need.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.icodeguru.com/CPP/CppTemplateMetaprogramming/ch10lev1sec5.html

If we had to boil the problem solved by [Blitz++](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blitz%2B%2B) down to a single sentence, we'd say, "A naive implementation of array math is horribly inefficient for any interesting computation." To see what we mean, take the boring statement

```
x = a + b + c;
```

The problem here is that the *operator+* signature above is just too greedy: It tries to evaluate *a* + *b* just as soon as it can, rather than waiting until the whole expression, including the addition of *c*, is available.

In the expression's parse tree, evaluation starts at the leaves and proceeds upwards to the root. What's needed here is some way of delaying evaluation until the library has all of the expression's parts: that is, until the assignment operator is executed. The stratagem taken by Blitz++ is to build a replica of the compiler's parse tree for the whole expression, allowing it to manage evaluation from the top down

This can't be any ordinary parse tree, though: Since array expressions may involve other operations like multiplication, which require their own evaluation strategies, and since expressions can be arbitrarily large and nested, a parse tree built with nodes and pointers would have to be traversed at runtime by the Blitz++ evaluation engine to discover its structure, thereby limiting performance. Furthermore, Blitz++ would have to use some kind of runtime dispatching to handle the different combinations of operation types, again limiting performance.

Instead, Blitz++ builds a compile-time parse tree out of expression templates. Here's how it works in a nutshell: Instead of returning a newly computed Array, operators just package up references to their arguments in an Expression instance, labeled with the operation:

```
// Operation tags
struct plus; struct minus;

// Expression tree node
template <class L, class OpTag, class R>
struct Expression
{
    Expression(L const& l, R const& r)
      : l(l), r(r) {}

    float operator[](unsigned index) const;

    L const& l;
    R const& r;
};

// Addition operator
template <class L, class R>
Expression<L,plus,R> operator+(L const& l, R const& r)
{
    return Expression<L,plus,R>(l, r);
}
```

Notice that when we write *a + b*, we still have all the information needed to do the computation. It's encoded in the type Expression<Array,plus,Array> and the data is accessible through the expression's stored references. When we write *a + b + c*, we get a result of type:

```
Expression<Expression<Array,plus,Array>,plus,Array>
```

Comment: A bit of description along with the link would be helpful. :)

Comment: What kind of description do you need?

Comment: Me? None. But someone reading this question, and skimming over the answers might not want to have to click on a link for every answer just to get an overview of the answers. If there are a lot of answers, it's nice to be able to get a rough idea of what each of them covers without having to visit external pages. It also helps if people read this answer a year or two from now, when the page you linked to is changed or even taken down. And finally, it gives us a reason to upvote your answer, when it actually reads like an answer, rather than simply directions on where to go to *find* an answer.

Comment: It's just SO etiquette to post a short summary along with the link, instead of link-only answers. :)

Comment: I think you are right. I linked the same thing, and you got 10 points and I got nothing. So I copied some sentences from it.

Comment: The link is broken (*"This webpage was generated by the domain owner using Sedo Domain Parking."*)

Comment: Re *"I copied some sentences from it"*: That is [plagiarism](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/plagiarism#Noun). If you copy something it must be ***very*** clearly marked as such (a link is not sufficient). Related: *[What do we do with answers that are entirely copied and improperly attributed (only a "reference" link or similar is included)?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/321299/)*

Comment: @PeterMortensen Sorry Peter! Thanks for pointing out this plagiarism, I think I really did a mistake 13 years ago! The link is broken now, but you can search for the content, and here is a working link, I hope it will last some years. I just copied the sentences from that place.
http://www.icodeguru.com/CPP/CppTemplateMetaprogramming/ch10lev1sec5.html